# ASP.NET MVC Chart: how to show values on each column

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts, view-helpers

I'm trying to use the Chart functionnality provided by the .NET framework, but I need a result that I can't do actually.

**My code:**

```
string themeChart = @"<Chart>
                      <ChartAreas>
                        <ChartArea Name=""Default"" _Template_=""All"">
                          <AxisY>
                            <LabelStyle Font=""Verdana, 12px"" />
                          </AxisY>
                          <AxisX LineColor=""64, 64, 64, 64"" Interval=""1"">
                            <LabelStyle Font=""Verdana, 12px"" />
                          </AxisX>
                        </ChartArea>
                      </ChartAreas>
                    </Chart>";


 var dataChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 300, theme: themeChart).AddSeries(
      chartType: "column",
      xValue: arrayXVal,
      yValues: arrayYVal)
           .AddTitle("ChartTitle")
           .GetBytes("png");

 return File(dataChart, "image/png");
```

My chart is like this picture.
[image: Now]

I need to do a chart like this:
[image]

The values can be above the columns or "in" like in the second image.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**: I found this page : [W3School page](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_chart.asp). You can see that there is an image who illustrate what I need. But the code is not provided...

**EDIT 2**: I also found this page: [Displaying Data in a Chart with ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor)](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart) but the code is not provided.

**Answer:**
Due to your answers, I tried to use `DataVisualization.Charting` and, with nearly no changes from my previous code, it gave me an acceptable result.

You can find my full code here:
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(1000, 300);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
            var chart1 = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
            chart1.Width = 1000;
            chart1.Height = 300;
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add("xAxis").BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            chart1.Titles.Add("Chart title");
            chart1.Series.Add("xAxis");

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series["xAxis"].Points.AddXY(i + " h", arrayValues[i]);
        }

        chart1.Series["xAxis"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        chart1.Series["xAxis"].LabelForeColor = Color.Black;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chart1.BackColor = Color.White;

        MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
        chart1.SaveImage(imageStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        chart1.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High;
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        imageStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        g.Dispose();
        image.Dispose();
        return null;
```

Thanks a lot Balthy for your answer.

I'll give the bounty to Balthy, because it's the first and complete answer.

I'll mark Adithya Kumaranchath's answer as "main answer" because he describes with more details the steps to follow.

Comment: the Chart class, is it your own implementation or a 3rd party ?

Comment: @AlexPeta: I use the Chart Helper, it's by default in the .NET framework (doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.chart(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: just decompiled the dll and took a look at it. did you try the AddLegend method also?

Comment: I'm not able to decompile the dll, I hope there's a easier way to do what I want. The AddLegend add a legend to the right side of the chart with a color code related to the data.

Comment: So the idea that i have in mind is like this : because the functionality is not out of the box, you have to wrap it yourself. And now you have 2 options, either do it on the client side, or on  the server side. Since the "client" side is not something that you can work with (SVG or Canvas) you should do this at the server side and you need to decompile the DLL to understand how that image is generated and how you can inject / influence it with your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the part that you do not want to touch the server side code but the options seem to be limited. I am not sure if you can do that but if you can change the server side, you sure can make these changes.

I have done this for you:

1. Add System.Web.DataVisualization; to your MVC website.
2. Add "using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;" to your controller.
3. Include the below code in your controller:

   ```
            public ActionResult CreateChart()
            {   
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(500, 50);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
            var chart1 = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
            chart1.Width = 1000;
            chart1.Height = 300;
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add("xAxis").BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb     (64,System.Drawing.Color.White);
            chart1.Series.Add("xAxis");
            chart1.Series["xAxis"].Points.AddY(8);
            chart1.Series["xAxis"].Points.AddY(8);
            chart1.Series["xAxis"].Points.AddY(8);
            chart1.Series["xAxis"].Points.AddY(6);
            chart1.Series["xAxis"].Points.AddY(5);    
            chart1.Series["xAxis"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            chart1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
            chart1.SaveImage(imageStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            chart1.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.SystemDefault;
            Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            imageStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            g.Dispose();
            image.Dispose();
            return null;
       }
   ```
4. Include the below piece of code in your view where you want to see the chart.
5. Now run the code and you will be able to see this.

   [image]

Customize the params as needed. Hope this helps.

Comment: any help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133293/how-to-show-min-and-max-in-range-bar-using-system-web-ui-datavisualization-chart

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to interact with the points directly to add a Label value.
Hopefully this short example will be of some use. It adds the Chart Area in code rather than the xml theme, but I am sure it could be swapped if necessary.

```
public ActionResult Chart()
{
    var chart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
    chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());

    // Dummy data
    var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(i => new { Name = i.ToString(), Count = i }).ToArray();

    chart.Series.Add(new Series("Data"));
    chart.Series["Data"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

    for (int x = 0; x < data.Length; x++)
    {
        // Add each point and set its Label
        int ptIdx = chart.Series["Data"].Points.AddXY(
             data[x].Name,
             data[x].Count);
        DataPoint pt = chart.Series["Data"].Points[ptIdx];
        pt.Label = "#VALX: #VALY";
        pt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12f, FontStyle.Bold);
        pt.LabelForeColor = Color.Green;
    }

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
    }
}
```

Then in my razor view I simply have:

```
<img alt="alternateText" src="@Url.Action("Chart")" />
```

The `pt.Label` value is a kind of format string and can use `"#VALX"` or `"#VALY"` to show only one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to the xml in your code to show a number above every data point

```
<Series>
  <Series Name=""Default"" IsValueShownAsLabel=""true""></Series>
</Series>
```

then add a name to your chart series in your chart object

```
var dataChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 300, theme: themeChart).AddSeries(
  name:"Default",
  chartType: "column",
```

the name in your xml series should match the name in chart object